# Are there too many their in my sentence?

Tags: word-usage, repetition

Travelling around the world for tourism and business gave me the chance to meet many people in developing countries. When I hear about **their lives in their** home countries, I can relate to their desire for better lives.

Should keep the first two "their"s, as I have bolded.

P.S is it better to say "Travelling around the world for **both** tourism and business" ?

Comment: @kanne The correct (and only) British spelling of *travelling* is with two *l*s. Other countries, such as Canada, can also spell it with two *l*s.

Comment: Why do you think that using **their** twice is ungrammatical, or otherwise wrong?

Comment: @JasonBassford I think it sounds abit ridiculous to use their so repetitively in one sentence.

Comment: I've no problem with the three _their_'s: such common words tend to be backgrounded. More jarring is the repetition of _lives_. And the tense mismatch.

Comment: @A6ftMan Fair enough, then don't repeat it. If you don't like how something sounds, then rephrase it. :)  But this the discussion around this will be more opinion based than anything else.

Answer (score -2):

Repetition is a problem in writing. (unless it's poetry or writing in a creative way, like Doctor Seuss.)

When I hear about their lives in their home countries, I can relate to their desire for better lives.

I would replace one of the "their" like this:
"When I hear about their lives and home countries, I can relate to their desire for better lives."

Also,  "Travelling around the world for both tourism and business" 
Does sound better.

I hoped I helped.